# Filter posts by specific custom category and current tag

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have set up a custom post type (buyers_club)  with a custom category (buyers-club) and custom tags (country). I'd like to show a list of related posts by specific category, FEATURED, and by the current tag.

So far I have this but it isn't working:

```
<ul>
<?php
$country_name = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'country' ) );
query_posts('post_type=buyers_club&buyers-club=featured&country= .$country_name . &showposts=5');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
</ul>
```

Can anybody help?

UPDATE

I have changed it to this with mixed results. I have one query that gets the posts of a specified category and current tag. This works except that it does not exclude the current post from the list:

```
 <?php
        $country_name = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'country' ) );
        $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'buyers_club',
        'buyers-club'    => 'Featured',
        'country' => $country_name,
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'exclude' => $post->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 5

        );
        query_posts( $args );

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
        endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Then I have a query that gets related posts from the current category AND current tag. This does not work:

```
<?php
        $country_name = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'country' ) );
        $category_name = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'buyers-club' ) );
        $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'buyers_club',
        'buyers-club'    => $category_name,
        'country' => $country_name, 
        'order'    => 'rand',
    'exclude' => $post->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 5
        );
        query_posts( $args );

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
        endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: For starters, you're missing single quotes before and after the concatenation: `...country='.$country_name.'$showposts=5`. If this is still not working: HOW is is not working? And BTW, you should use `WP_Query`!

Comment: `showposts` is deprecated. Use `posts_per_page` instead

Comment: @JMa Thanks for getting back so quickly. I have updated my question. As for what is not working... well it's simply not returning a list of the post titles and it is not excluding the current post.

Comment: @JMa Ok I got the second Query working, I needed to separate the terms with commas. All I need do now is exclude the current post. Any ideas?

Comment: never use `query_posts` for second query >>[When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Answer (score 1):

There is a descriptively named argument to [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), which is what you should be using, called `post__not_in` which excludes any post `ID`s passed into it.

Also, the `{tax} => {term_name}` pattern that you have used twice is deprecated. You should be using a `tax_query` argument instead.

Lines like this one, `strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'buyers-club' ) );`, will fail if more than one term is returned. That is not the way you should be doing this. That function isn't meant for returning a list of slugs.

It should look something more like this:

```
$country_name = wp_list_pluck(get_the_terms( 1, 'country' ), 'term_id')
$category_name = wp_list_pluck(get_the_terms( 1, 'buyers-club' ), 'term_id')
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'buyers_club',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'buyers-club',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $category_name
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'country',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $country_name
    )
  ),
  'order'    => 'rand',
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$buyer_club = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($buyer_club->have_posts()) {
  while ( $buyer_club->have_posts() ) {
    $buyer_club->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however it's not returning anything at all now.

Comment: Do you need an `OR` relationship betwen the meta fields?

Comment: Typo-- "buyer" not "buyers". Check again. One big problem with questions like this is that it is nearly impossible to test properly as I don't have your data in my database.